# Issue ordering by date with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

  user: String,
  imagen: [{ 

              name: String,
              author: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

           }],
  follow: [String]

});
```

And this is the code:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

        usermodel.find({ _id: {$in: user.follow } }, function (err, images){

          console.log(images);

           if (err) throw err;

            res.render('home.ejs', {

              user: user,
              following: images

            });

         });

});
```

The follow array in the Schema contains the `_id`s of the users that the actual user is following. I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
{ _id: 50fd9c7b8e6a9d087d000006,
   imagen: 
    [ { name: 'fff.png',
        author: 'foo',
        _id: 50fd9ca2bc9f163e7d000006,
        date: Mon Jan 21 2013 20:53:06 GMT+0100 (CET) },
      { name: 'mmm.png',
        author: 'foo',
        _id: 50fda83a3214babc88000005,
        date: Mon Jan 21 2013 21:41:34 GMT+0100 (CET) } ] },
 { _id: 50fd9d3ce20da1dd7d000006,
        imagen: 
          [ { name: 'ddd.jpg',
              author: 'faa',
              _id: 50fda815915e068387000005,
              date: Mon Jan 21 2013 21:42:57 GMT+0100 (CET) } ] }
```

And I'm trying to get an output similar at this, for example:

```
  { [ { name: 'fff.png',
        author: 'foo',
        _id: 50fd9ca2bc9f163e7d000006,
        date: Mon Jan 21 2013 20:53:06 GMT+0100 (CET) },
      { name: 'ddd.png',
        author: 'faa',
        _id: 50fda815915e068387000005,
        date: Mon Jan 21 2013 21:42:34 GMT+0100 (CET) }, 
       { name: 'mmm.png',
        author: 'foo',
        _id: 50fda83a3214babc88000005,
        date: Mon Jan 21 2013 21:41:34 GMT+0100 (CET) }
  ] }
```

I think that what I want is imposible, or very complex, is there any solution for this...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: You may use `array1.concat(array2)` with a loop to join all `imagen` arrays together and sort the result array by date after that. I don't  think that mongoose sorting will help here. Hope i understood your question in the right way.

Comment: But everything that I do inside a `for`loop, for example, it disappears when the loop ends, and I do something with the data used inside the loop, using it outside the loop, the data is the same, the for loop doesn't change it. I guess because I have to code it in a asynchronous way.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
usermodel.find({ _id: {$in: user.follow } }, function (err, images){
```

`images` is not good name, nicer name is `users` or even `docs` (you'll have an array of documents of usermodel schema there). So `images` in your code are found documents.

I've made a little test with the same schema as you gave. Here is the part where I join all `user.imagen` arrays and then sort them (of course it is test case but it works, hope this will lead you to the right way):

```
User.find {}, (err, users) ->
  all_images = []
  # iterate users array to join all imagen arrays
  for user in users
    all_images.push user.imagen
  # flatten nested arrays in all_images with underscore function
  all_images = _.flatten all_images
  # sort all_images the way you want (i.e. descending)
  all_images.sort (a, b) -> b.date - a.date
  # render page and see that it works
  res.render 'test.html', {images: all_images}
```